# How to get Visual Studio Intellisense errors from command-line

Tags: .net, visual-studio, command-line, msbuild

We have a build process that uses MSBuild to compile our solution.  When I compile that way, there are no errors in the build.  But when I execute a build from inside of Visual Studio, in the Error List tab, I have about 20 errors when I display "Build + IntelliSense".

Is there a way to get that same error list from a command line utility?   It is not currently part of the MSBuild output (these errors are not in the Output tab either).

Comment: +1 for a question that would have never crossed my mind to ask... but just curious, why? The compiler is right 100% of the times, so what does the Intellisense noise help with.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, the compiler itself is enough to generate a xx.exe or xx.dll. But intellisense can also be useful to improve coding format, for example it would provide `messages` like the method name would be better if it begins with upper case chars. IntelliSense is also a code-completion aid that includes a number of features: List Members, Parameter Info, Quick Info, and Complete Word.

Comment: And for specific scenario, some users may have one big project/solution which will take 10+minutes(or 30+ I once met) to compile. So it's important to correct the mistakes via help of intellisense before building/compiling them. Otherwise we have to spend another ten minutes or even more...

Comment: @dxiv We also have an OWASP checker integrated in to look for security violations, the output is part of Build + Intellisense.  The idea is to cause a build failure on our integration server when there are security violations.

Comment: Thanks to the OP and @LanceLi-MSFT for the additional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get that same error list from a command line
> utility? It is not currently part of the MSBuild output (these errors
> are not in the Output tab either).

For now msbuild can't get **same** error list like what `Build + IntelliSense` provides. To get same warnings you can try [using csc.exe directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe#sample-command-lines-for-the-c-compiler) from command-line.

Roslyn(Roslyn=>csc.exe) is not only the C# compiler, but also the API for code analyzing. In my test, it can display more warnings than msbuild. (Such as [CS0168](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0168), msbuild won't output this warning)

Comment: From what I can tell, Roslyn has no notion of project and solution files, making it very unuseful to try compiling big projects this way. I would love to be able to see intellisense suggestions as part of a jenkins build job report to monitor the code quality. Any suggestions?